# How do I get specific rows of a matrix and all columns of this rows? in Python

Tags: python, matrix, bit

I have a vector of bits B[] and a matrix NxN. I'd like to get all rows of the matrix where the bit in my B[] vector is 1. For example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic for loop:

```
b = [1,0,1,1]
Matrix = [['a','b','c','d'],['e','f','g','h'],['i','j','k','l'],['m','n','o','p']]

result_matrix = []
for i in range(len(b)):
    if b[i] == 1:
        result_matrix.append(Matrix[i])
print (result_matrix)
```

what is equal list comprehension:

```
result_matrix = [Matrix[i] for i in range(len(b)) if b[i]]
print (result_matrix)
```

Comment: your welcom, Im glad that I helped :)  
otherwise do not forget to upvote or accept an answer :)

Comment: can you edit your post with matrix that you are using in your code

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using numpy arrays for various reasons. You can than use true multidimensional arrays. Than you will be able to use the following

To select specific rows of a matrix you can use:

```
b(4,:)
```

If condition is a function returning a logical list you can display all rows meeting a condition:

```
b(condition(),:)
```

In your case you can use:

```
result_matrix = Matrix[b[:,0] == 1,:]
```